# How do you connect Laravel 5.4 with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, google-app-engine-python

1. I am adding this line in the composer.json

   "shpasser/gae-support-l5": "~1.0"

   2. then I ran composer update
   3. I am adding this provide in app.php:  `Shpasser\GaeSupportL5\GaeSupportServiceProvider::class`
   4. then I ran php artisan optimize

I am getting the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()
```